# Better performance to store images for a dynamic grid on a .Net windows form?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, image-processing, picturebox

We have thousands of products and the product information is stored on the database. The images for the products are stored on a network hard drive. Pulling the images, sizing and displaying them on a grid with product information for a quote that has over 900 different products took so long that although it completed the code, it did not completely paint the display.

```
        If webcontent IsNot Nothing Then
        itemRow.ItemWebHead = webcontent.WebHead
        Dim imgNames As String = webcontent.ImageName
        Dim imgNamesCol As New List(Of String)(Split(imgNames, VM))
        itemRow.ImageConfig = New dataSourceQuote.PictureBoxConfig(imgNamesCol)
        If imgNamesCol.Count = 1 Then
            itemRow.ImagePath = ImgHelperClass.WebImagePath + ImgHelperClass.SetImageFileWithRes(imgNamesCol(0), ImgHelperClass.WebImageRes)
        ElseIf imgNamesCol.Count > 1 Then
            itemRow.ImagePath = ImgHelperClass.WebImagePath + ImgHelperClass.SetImageFileWithRes(imgNamesCol(0), ImgHelperClass.WebImageRes)
        ElseIf imgNamesCol.Count = 0 Then
            itemRow.ImagePath = ImgHelperClass.strSaveLocation + "\" + ImgHelperClass.ImageNotAvailable
        End If

        itemRow.Description = Me.GetSpecsString(webcontent)

    Else
        itemRow.ImageConfig = New dataSourceQuote.PictureBoxConfig(Nothing)
        itemRow.ImagePath = ImgHelperClass.strSaveLocation + "\" + ImgHelperClass.ImageNotAvailable
    End If
```

Would it be faster if the images were stored on a SQL database instead of a network drive?

Comment: What sort of grid? Is it DGV? Have you considered only showing what's actually visible (Virtual mode)?

Comment: Download only images that fit on the window and process them to reduce its size to the appropriate size. Are you downloading 5Mb images and showing them in a 200x200 picture box? or something like that?

Comment: Rather than burning server CPU scaling images while servicing every web request have you considered storing the the scaled images in a persistent cache? Or even prescaling them in a directory hierarchy with say original, 1/4 and thumbnail scales?